# windows context menu %1 extends file name with wrong diacritics

Tags: c, windows

I've made a Windows Context Menu item like this :
key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Test\command
command: "c:\Test.exe" "%1"

The %1 is not expanded as expected when sending "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Testă.pdf" I receive the fallowing string : "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Testa.pdf"
The "ă" is being replaced with "a" and I don't want that.
Is tis an encoding problem ? can someon help me please ?

Comment: What language is Test.exe in?  If C/C++, is it compiled as UNICODE or ANSI?

Comment: It's in C. It's only printing the args to a file with fprintf(). I compiled it using #undef UNICODE and #undef _UNICODE from a VisualStudio project, but I've got the same result. The problem must be in how windows expands "%1".

Comment: Could it be that you are printing this on a non-unicode console?

Comment: Windows is expanding %1 just fine. The problem is that your program is non-Unicode, so you are unable to see the full character repertoire. Even when you switch to Unicode, you are using `fprintf` which does not support Unicode. And your console may not support the character in question. Look at the string in the debugger; don't trust printf

Comment: I tried opening a file with windows CreateFile() and writing the bytes of the args directly with WriteFile() but when I open the file the content is still wrong (I opened with notepad and wordpad).The Test.exe is a test I made to see how windows passes the argumets of context menues to executables. I have a separate project done in Java wich has a launch4j executable wrapper over a jar, and the jar receives the file path incorecly for files wich have diacritics :(. Not sure it is a matter of how I print the strings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found the problem. My program was using "int main(int argc, char** argv)" and even after using the windows function MultiByteToWideChar() the result was stil the same. After modifiing to "int wmain (int argc, PWSTR* argv)", I finally got the result I was looking for.

It seems that windows sends unicode bytes only to "wmain".